# Username regex validation with an optional dot and specific string limit

Tags: regex

I am writing an expression to validate a username with the following requirements:

- length between 6 and 20,
- must start with a letter,
- numbers are allowed,
- dot is optional or only one is allowed.
- must not end with a dot

Tried with but didn't work:

```
^(([a-zA-Z])(\.{0,1})([a-zA-Z0-9]*)){6,20}$
```

another option

```
^([a-zA-Z]+([\\.]?)+([a-zA-Z0-9]*)){6,20}$
```

Comment: `^(?!(?:[^.]*\.){2})[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.]{5,19}$`

Comment: recommended tool for regex problems https://regexr.com/

Comment: This expression worked , Thanks Wiktor

Comment: Must not end with a dot condition added, it fails in that case

Answer (score 2):

You may use an expression that will match a letter at the start and the 5 to 19 letters, digits or dots that should only appear in the middle of the string.

You may use

```
^(?=.{5,19}$)(?=[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/962nsH/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{5,19}$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a string that contains any five to nineteen characters other than line break chars
- `(?=[A-Za-z])`  - the first char must be an ASCII letter
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - one or more letters or digits
- `(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - one or more letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Must not end with a dot condition added, it fails in that case

Comment: ^(?!(?:[^.]*\.){2})[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.]{5,19}$(?<!\\.)

Comment: @theSecretCoder I updated the solution in the answer. If you need more clarifications, please let know.